# Is there a way to stop Outlook from breaking padding of <div>

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

I've built an email template with Mailchimp which uses a custom code block. I use this to remove the padding between my header images and content block Mailchimp automatically between images and content.

I've used a  tag, along with some styling to add padding around the text in the content block. In most email clients (gmail, safari) it looks fine. Only Outlook breaks the padding and makes the text stick to the edge of the content block.

I've tried adding a table around the  tags, but this doesn't seem to work.

The code i'm using is pasted below:

```html
<div class="mcnTextContent" style="background-color: #b3daf0; padding: 20px;">
<h1 style="color: #000000; text-align: left; font-size: 18pt; font-family: Tahoma, Open Sans;">Hallo!</h1>
<p style="color: #000000; text-align: left; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Tahoma, Open Sans;">Op zoek naar de beste deal? Snuffel dan even rond in onze Online Outlet! Met kortingscode FIETSOUTLET krijg je in je winkelmand namelijk nog eens <b>10% extra korting</b> op <a ><br>
</div>
```

I expect to see 20px padding around the text, which it does show in gmail. But not in Outlook.

Comment: Add a table inside the div to wrap the content and add padding on 'td'. It will work fine.. outlook wont support some styling properties on div and some other elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook has very poor support for inline styles. There's some useful info here (https://css-tricks.com/using-css-in-html-emails-the-real-story/) and here (https://templates.mailchimp.com/development/css/outlook-conditional-css/) the TL;DR of which is: Use table-based layout for consistency.

Its horrible, I know. ;(

```html
<table class="mcnTextContent" cellpadding="20">
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#b3daf0">
      <h1 style="color: #000000; text-align: left; font-size: 18pt; font-family: Tahoma, Open Sans;">Hallo!</h1>
      <p style="color: #000000; text-align: left; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Tahoma, Open Sans;">Op zoek naar de beste deal? Snuffel dan even rond in onze Online Outlet! Met kortingscode FIETSOUTLET krijg je in je winkelmand namelijk nog eens <b>10% extra korting</b> op
        <p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Great, thanks! That solved the issue with padding in Outlook!

One of my collagues pointed out that on his iPhone 7 the styling of the text (Tahoma) is removed. Is there a way to force the correct font to be used on every device?

Comment: @Roeland Tahoma is not an iOS system font and so may not be available to your users' (unless they have installed it separately). See: http://iosfonts.com/ for a list of native fonts. You could use Adobe typekit or some other font provider to embed the font in your email (eg: https://helpx.adobe.com/fonts/using/html-email.html) but I expect Outlook won't honour it. Perhaps choose a different font?
P.S. If my answer has solved your problem you should mark it as accepted. ;)

Comment: thanks! I've set up some extra fallback fonts which kinda look like Tahoma which are available on iOS. And I've marked your answer :)